# Получение результата запроса RxJava2 + Room

Tags: rxandroid, rxjava2, android-room

Не могу разобраться с получением данных после запроса, в конечном итоге необходимо вернуть объект Note, но как это написать не понимаю, бьюсь над проблемой не первый день.

При всех попытках получить результат ловил NullPointerException

[Ссылка на репозиторий проекта](https://gitlab.com/vladislav.doremi/password-manager)

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM note WHERE id = :id")
Maybe<Note> getItemById(int id);
```

Repository

```
public Note getItemById(final int noteId) {
  return mNoteDao.getItemById(noteId)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(new DisposableMaybeObserver<Note>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Note note) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
      });
```

}

ViewModel

```
public Note getItemById(int noteId) {
    return mNoteRepository.getItemById(noteId);
}
```

Необходимый результат

```
Note note = viewModel.getItemById(int id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный найденый вариант, это вызов функции в

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Note note) {

}
```

и передача в нее объекта с последующей обработкой на стороне уже внешней функции.